# How do I forward gmail raw email to a web service?

Tags: api, email, service, forwarding

I want to forward the raw email from my gmail to, say,

POST www.mywebsite.com/api/something?email={raw-email}

I feel like there ought to be an easy way to do this.. but my searches have turned up nothing.  We'd prefer to use gmail, but if you know how I can do this with any mail server, that's helpful too.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you propose iterating through your Gmail account's messages?

Comment: I was kinda hoping there was a mail client that would receive the mail and then forward the contents to a URL, or that gmail had some script built in. I don't want it on past emails.. just new emails, as they come in.

Similar to forwarding your email to another address. I just want to forward the raw text to a web service.